# Customized column (accnt number) returning NULL value in journal voucher

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am new in NetSuite development and I have encountered an issue on displaying the value of a customized *column*, *accnt number*, in journal voucher.

We created the column to separate and get the account number of an account. For example *11110000 Cash In bank Peso -Clearing Accounts*, *accnt number(custcol6)* column is displaying *11110000*.

I attached a sample transaction here and the printout for your reference.

[Sample Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdWlC.png)

[Sample Printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeWyQ.png)

Thank you so much!

Comment: I can't post my code :(

Comment: Why can't you post your code ?

Comment: because it too long :(

Comment: you can post only the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Okay sir. I will get the code

Comment: if(search.length>0){

for(var x = 0;x<search.length;x++){

if(search[x].getValue('debitamount')>0){
layout += '<tr rowspan="1">';
layout += '<td align="center" colspan="1" line-height="150%">'+(search[x].getText('custcol6'))+'</td>';
layout += '<td align="left" colspan="1" line-height="150%">'+ampchange((search[x].getText('account')));

Comment: I see,. you are doing the pdf in script not thru free marker. Anyway, why do you use getText instead of getValue for custcol6?

Comment: Yes its not thru free marker. Either getText or getValue, the result is still null.

Comment: Did you try using `search[x].getField('account')` instead? If the result is same then probably we need to know what is `search[x]` because it seems like you're operating on a line item value and your code looking for the value in body field.

Comment: I used also `getField` but I got same result. I used this search : `var search = nlapiSearchRecord('journalentry',-36, filters);` and I think `-36` is default of NetSuite?

Comment: If you're pulling results from a saved search you probably need to put the string `internalid` of the search instead of `-36`.

Comment: Or maybe use formulatext for the column.